# Sort XML-File by Tag-content

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a lot of XML-Files which aren't sorted. I'd like to sort them by a tag-content named "title". I know the order of titles:
1.) editorial
2.) content
3.) club
etc.
Each file has another "title"-content.

The XML-structure of file number 1 looks like this:

```
<article>
<someTags>
</someTags>
<title>editorial</title>
</article>
```

How can I go through all files and sort them by the defined order?
The file-names can look like: "sorted_01.xml", "sorted_02.xml" and so on.
How can I get this?
Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Comment: With the given xml sample, we can't figure out the structure of the xml. Could you post another sample that contains at least 2 `title` tags?

Comment: Each file has exactly 1 title-tag. The content is different. The file with the title-content "editorial" should become the first file, the file with the title-content "content" the second file and so on :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sort`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) or [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with the function that return the text of the `title` tag as a key function.

```
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_title(filepath):
    tree = ET.parse(filepath)
    return tree.find('.//title').text
    # Find `title` element and return the text of the element.

filepaths = glob.glob('*.xml')
print(sorted(filepaths, key=get_title))
```

See [demo](http://asciinema.org/a/7660).

Comment: But how can I determine the order in which the files are saved? I mean: the file with the "editorial"-title-content should be saved as 01.xml, the file with the "content"-title-content as "02.xml" and so on. I do have to save the order of tag-contents in a list, don't I?

Comment: @MarkF6, It seems like I misunderstood your question. Check out Guy Gavriely's answer.

Answer (score 1):

another way to do it (wasn't tested)

```
import glob, os
from lxml import etree
d = {}
titles = ['editorial', 'content' , 'club', ...] # ordered titles
for fname in glob.glob('*.xml'):
     tree = etree.parse(fname)
     title = tree.xpath('//title/text()')[0]
     subtitle = tree.xpath('//subtitle/text()')[0]
     key = '%s_%s' % (title, subtitle)
     d[key] = fname
for idx,title in enumerate(titles, 1):
     os.rename(d[title], 'sorted_%02d.xml' % idx)
```

Comment: Use simply `for` loop (especially when the expression in the list comprehension does not yield meaningful value + has side effect)

Comment: I didn't tested your code, but your code will  not work because `xpath` returns a list which is not hashable; cannot be used as dictionary key.

Comment: In addition to that, the code does not populate the `arr` list.

Comment: update, both of your remarks are correct (also your code) :) thanks @falsetru

Comment: +1 on your answer @falsetru, I've been seeing you around and love your work

Comment: Slightly modified your code to produce `sorted_01.xml` instead of `sorted_0.xml`, ...

Comment: I got the error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'" for this line: "d = {lxml.parse(fname).xpath('//title/text()')[0]:fname for fname in glob.glob('*.xml')}" 
Why?

Comment: Now I got the following error: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'etree'" :S

Comment: Now, it works. Thanks a lot. I've 1 question left: How is it possible to concatenate the content of the tag "title" AND "subtitle in d?

Comment: so subtitle is another field coming from the input file but is not used as a key, right?

Comment: updated again subtitle is added and the data structure changed to a dict to have both values in it

Comment: The problem is: The titles which I save in "titles" are composed of the content of the title-tag AND of the content of the subtitle-content. Sorry, I didn't see this before :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47577/discussion-between-guy-gavriely-and-markf6)

Comment: Ok, I answered / asked in the chat. :)